# Animations inside collection cells?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collection. Inside there are `imageViews`, with images assigned. For some cells, I am trying to set animations (to the cell's image) .

What happens, is that if I set *cell 1 animation it works*, but as soon as I add a new cell that has animation , **1 stops , and the new cell works.**

The cell loading in the collection controller :

```
 internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FlowViewCell

      //animation load
        cell.animate()
```

and Inside a cell, I animate with this function :

```
  func animate (_ kind:String )
    {


            let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
            rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
            rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0)
            rotateAnimation.duration = 1.0/circlePerSecond
            rotateAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity

            image.layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)


        }
```

Probably related to reusable cells, but how one can **get multiple cells to be able to animate each his own animation** ?

Comment: Perhaps you should remove existing animation before adding a new one to a reused cell. Just add a key for it instead of nil and fetch it with animation(forKey: "rotationAnimation")

Comment: tried that with image.layer.removeAllAnimations() , didn't work ... some animation runs, other will stop running. every reload of the collection, different cells are running their animations .

Comment: You can try putting your animate() function to :     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {}

Comment: Tried just now, not working, the first will animate, then second cell will animate and first will stop .

Comment: @Curnelious I've been really struggling to reproduce your issue but with no luck. All I can do is to share a working project and you can either find your mistake by comparing the code or edit test project to reproduce the issue if I misunderstood your situation. Here is the project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wi74xojeqlpjvlp/StackOverflow.zip?dl=0

Comment: @alex thanks a lot for your effort! , well this is not exactly the same , your project is doing very basic thing, you open the collection and there you have 5 elements. But when things get complexed you add new cells dynamically, and you have 15 cells , you have invisible cells, you have a dynamically reloading collection. Everything changes then . But thanks a lot again.